# Simple method to modify json keys casing to camelCase from snake_case

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have lots of json parsing and all the json I am receiving is having keys in snake case like `user_name`. And for parsing I need it in camel case like `userName`.

The sample json file would look like this:

```
[{
   "user_id" : 1,
   "user_name" : "Abcd"
},
{
   "org_id" : 11,
   "org_name" : "some_name"
}
...
]
```

Expected output:

```
[{
   "userId" : 1,
   "userName" : "Abcd"
},
{
   "orgId" : 11,
   "orgName" : "some_name"
}
...
]
```

The json I am receiving is not having any particular fixed notation and it can be anything. But all the keys will be in snake case. And I need to convert it to camelCase.

What I cannot do is, find and replace, because it also replace snake casing strings in values as well.

Is there any easy method, which can do the same?

Comment: Hi, Did you tried this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220750/11888809 You can do your thing in one line of code and it will work on nested objects as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use npm package called: `camelcase-keys-deep`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/camelcase-keys-deep

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var keys = [];//this will contain the json with desired output
for(var i = 0;i<myObj.length;i++)//myObj is the variable that contains your json
{
    Object.keys(myObj[i]).forEach(function(key){
        if(keys.indexOf(key) == -1)
        {
            var newValue = {};
            var value = myObj[i][key];
            key = key.replace(/_([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
            newValue[key] = value;
            keys.push(newValue);
        }   
    });

}
//console.log(keys);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

So [AKSHAY JAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7610129/akshay-jain)'s implementation is pretty solid but it will delete the properties that are not in snake case. I fixed the implementation.

```
var arr = [{
  "user_id": 1,
  "user_name": "Abcd"
},
{
  "org_id": 11,
"org_name": "some_name"
},
{
  "personId": 12,
  "personName": "otherName"
}];

arr.forEach(a => {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(k => {
      newK = k.replace(/(\_\w)/g, (m) => m[1].toUpperCase());
      if (newK != k) {
        a[newK] = a[k];
        delete a[k];
      }
    });
  });

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If u use lodash I would suggest my solution for this:

**snake_case -> camelCase**

```
function camelCaseDeep(anything) {
  const thing = _.cloneDeep(anything);

  if (
    _.isEmpty(thing) ||
    (!_.isObject(thing) && !_.isArray(thing))
  ) {
    return thing;
  }

  if (_.isArray(thing)) {
    const arr = thing;
    return arr.map(el => camelCaseDeep(el))
  }

  // thing can be only not empty object here
  const objWithMappedKeys = _.mapKeys(thing, (value, key) => _.camelCase(key));
  const objWithMappedValues = _.mapValues(objWithMappedKeys, value => camelCaseDeep(value));

  return objWithMappedValues;
}
```

**camelCase -> snake_case**

```
function snakeCaseDeep(anything) {
  const thing = _.cloneDeep(anything);

  if (
    _.isEmpty(thing) ||
    (!_.isObject(thing) && !_.isArray(thing))
  ) {
    return thing;
  }

  if (_.isArray(thing)) {
    const arr = thing;
    return arr.map(el => snakeCaseDeep(el))
  }

  // thing can be only not empty object here
  const objWithMappedKeys = _.mapKeys(thing, (value, key) => _.snakeCase(key));
  const objWithMappedValues = _.mapValues(objWithMappedKeys, value => snakeCaseDeep(value));

  return objWithMappedValues;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user_name": "Abcd"
  },
  {
    "org_id": 11,
    "org_name": "some_name"
  }
];

arr.forEach(a => {
  Object.keys(a).forEach(k => {
    newK = k.replace(/(\_\w)/g, (m) => m[1].toUpperCase());
    a[newK] = a[k];
    delete a[k];
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made this method simple to read, may not be optimal, but handles the problem.

```js
let a = {
       "fon_name":
          {
           "pei_pei": "powPow",
           "pa_pum": "chi_bum"
          },
         "oh_lord": "why"
        }
    
     console.log(snakeToCamel(a))
    
    function snakeToCamel(json) {
      for(key in json){
        let camelKeyArray = key.split("_")
        for(let i = 1; i<camelKeyArray.length; i++){
          camelKeyArray[i] = camelKeyArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + camelKeyArray[i].substring(1);
        }
    
        let camelKey = camelKeyArray.join('')
    
        if(camelKey != key){
          json[camelKey] = json[key];
          delete json[key]
        }
    
        if(json[camelKey] instanceof Object){
          json[camelKey] = snakeToCamel(json[camelKey])
        }
      }
      return json;
    }
```