# Recursively convert an object fields from snake case to camelCase

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, lodash

I had an object like this (fields in **snake_case**)

```
const obj = {
  vt_core_random: {
    user_details: {
      first_name: "xyz",
      last_name: "abc",
      groups: [
        {
          id: 1,
          group_type: "EXT"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          group_type: "INT"
        }
      ],
      address_type: {
        city_name: "nashik",
        state: {
          code_name: "MH",
          name: "Maharashtra"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I want to recursily convert its fields to **camelCase**, so the expected output is given below

```
const obj = {
  vtCoreRandom: {
    userDetails: {
      firstName: "xyz",
      lastName: "abc",
      groups: [
        {
          id: 1,
          groupType: "EXT"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          groupType: "INT"
        }
      ],
      addressType: {
        cityName: "LMN",
        state: {
          codeName: "KOP",
          name: "PSQ"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I tried using mapKeys() but I just can't wrap my head around the recursive part of this. any help is highly appreciated. Also I have the ability to use `lodash` if it makes the process any simpler

Answer (score 28):

You can use lodash's [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#transform) to create a recursive function that iterates the keys and converts them camel case with [`_.camelCase()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#camelCase). Transform can also handle arrays, so if the iterated object (`target)` is an array, we don't need to change the keys.

```js
const camelize = obj => _.transform(obj, (acc, value, key, target) => {
  const camelKey = _.isArray(target) ? key : _.camelCase(key);
  
  acc[camelKey] = _.isObject(value) ? camelize(value) : value;
});

const obj = {"vt_core_random":{"user_details":{"first_name":"xyz","last_name":"abc","groups":[{"id":1,"group_type":"EXT"},{"id":2,"group_type":"INT"}],"address_type":{"city_name":"nashik","state":{"code_name":"MH","name":"Maharashtra"}}}}};

const result = camelize(obj);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Typescript version:
```import { camelCase, isArray, transform, isObject } from "lodash";

const camelize = (obj: Record<string, unknown>) =>
  transform(obj, (result: Record<string, unknown>, value: unknown, key: string, target) => {
    const camelKey = isArray(target) ? key : camelCase(key);

    result[camelKey] = isObject(value) ? camelize(value as Record<string, unknown>) : value;
  });```

Answer (score 8):

## Plain JavaScript

(works for snake_case and kebap-case)

```js
const recursiveToCamel = item => {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    return item.map(el => recursiveToCamel(el));
  } else if (typeof item === 'function' || item !== Object(item)) {
    return item;
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => [
      key.replace(/([-_][a-z])/gi, c => c.toUpperCase().replace(/[-_]/g, '')),
      recursiveToCamel(value),
    ]),
  );
};
```

Here is a small demo using the object provided by the question:

```js
const obj = {
  vt_core_random: {
    user_details: {
      first_name: "xyz",
      last_name: "abc",
      groups: [{
          id: 1,
          group_type: "EXT"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          group_type: "INT"
        }
      ],
      address_type: {
        city_name: "nashik",
        state: {
          code_name: "MH",
          name: "Maharashtra"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const recursiveToCamel = item => {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    return item.map(el => recursiveToCamel(el));
  } else if (typeof item === 'function' || item !== Object(item)) {
    return item;
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => [
      key.replace(/([-_][a-z])/gi, c => c.toUpperCase().replace(/[-_]/g, '')),
      recursiveToCamel(value),
    ]),
  );
};

console.log(recursiveToCamel(obj));
```

## TypeScript

```js
const recursiveToCamel = (item: unknown): unknown => {
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    return item.map((el: unknown) => recursiveToCamel(el));
  } else if (typeof item === 'function' || item !== Object(item)) {
    return item;
  }
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item as Record<string, unknown>).map(
      ([key, value]: [string, unknown]) => [
        key.replace(/([-_][a-z])/gi, c => c.toUpperCase().replace(/[-_]/g, '')),
        recursiveToCamel(value),
      ],
    ),
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6):

For all the people using lodash I have manipulated the accepted answer since lodash already includes the utility functions like `isArray` `isObject` `camelCase`

So the code reduces to this. :)

```
function keysToCamel(obj) {
  if (isPlainObject(obj)) {
    const n = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => (n[camelCase(k)] = keysToCamel(obj[k])));
    return n;
  } else if (isArray(obj)) obj.map(i => keysToCamel(i));
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: This does not work because `isObject` in lodash returns true for arrays

`Checks if value is the language type of Object. (e.g. arrays, functions, objects, regexes, new Number(0), and new String(''))`

Comment: Typescript version:

```import { isPlainObject, camelCase, isArray } from "lodash";

function convertKeysToCamelCase(obj: unknown): unknown {
  if (isPlainObject(obj)) {
    const n = {};
    Object.keys(obj as object).forEach(
      (k) => (n[camelCase(k)] = convertKeysToCamelCase((obj as object)[k]))
    );
    return n;
  } else if (isArray(obj)) obj.map((i) => convertKeysToCamelCase(i));
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: In the `if else` statement, we should return the mapped array for it to work with Arrays of objects, Otherwises, objects inside arrays won't be transformed

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using typescript. I added typings to the accepted answer on this question.

```
const toCamel = (str: string): string => {
  return str.replace(/([_-][a-z])/gi, ($1: string) => {
    return $1.toUpperCase().replace('-', '').replace('_', '');
  });
};

const isArray = function (
  input: Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[] | unknown
): input is Record<string, unknown>[] {
  return Array.isArray(input);
};

const isObject = function (
  obj: Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[] | unknown
): obj is Record<string, unknown> {
  return (
    obj === Object(obj) && !Array.isArray(obj) && typeof obj !== 'function'
  );
};

const camelize = function <T>(input: T): T {
  return (function recurse<
    K extends Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[] | unknown
  >(input: K): K {
    if (isObject(input)) {
      return Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, key) => {
        return Object.assign(acc, { [toCamel(key)]: recurse(input[key]) });
      }, {} as K);
    } else if (isArray(input)) {
      return input.map((i) => recurse(i)) as K;
    }
    return input;
  })(input);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a fairly generic fashion, writing a function which accepts an arbitrary key-transformation function and returning one which accepts an object and returns one with the same structure but with keys transformed.  This is essentially no harder than writing code specifically for camelizing the keys.

Here is one approach:

```js
const fixKeys = (fn) => (obj) => Object .fromEntries (
  Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => [
    fn(k), 
    Array .isArray (v) ? v .map (fixKeys (fn)) : Object (v) === v ? fixKeys (fn) (v) : v
  ])
)

const camelCase = (s) => s.replace(/_(.)/g, (s, c) => c.toUpperCase())

const camelizeKeys = fixKeys (camelCase)

const obj = {vt_core_random: {user_details: {first_name: "xyz", last_name: "abc", groups: [{id: 1, group_type: "EXT"}, {id: 2, group_type: "INT"}], address_type: { city_name: "nashik", state: {code_name: "MH",  name: "Maharashtra"}}}}}

console .log (camelizeKeys (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) is not available in your environment it's easy enough to shim or replace.  Also, this is tagged "lodash", and if you're already using it, you might want to replace some of the custom functionality here with lodash function, including the `camelCase` function and the Array and Object tests.  Or not, as this is already fairly simple.

Comment: there is a little problem if the value of a property is null, because null type is 'object'.

from leonheess answer we could invert the object check to be:

`v !== Object(v) ? v : fixKeys (fn)(v)`

Comment: @Marcelo: You're right.  I've taken to using that in the last few years in place of `typeof`.  I updated the answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
  vt_core_random: {
    user_details: {
      first_name: "xyz",
      last_name: "abc",
      groups: [
        {
          id: 1,
          group_type: "EXT"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          group_type: "INT"
        }
      ],
      address_type: {
        city_name: "nashik",
        state: {
          code_name: "MH",
          name: "Maharashtra"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function toCamel(o) {
  var newO, origKey, newKey, value
  if (o instanceof Array) {
    return o.map(function(value) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
          value = toCamel(value)
        }
        return value
    })
  } else {
    newO = {}
    for (origKey in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
        newKey = _.camelCase(origKey)
        value = o[origKey]
        if (value instanceof Array || (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)) {
          value = toCamel(value)
        }
        newO[newKey] = value
      }
    }
  }
  return newO
}

console.log(toCamel(obj));    const obj = {
  vt_core_random: {
    user_details: {
      first_name: "xyz",
      last_name: "abc",
      groups: [
        {
          id: 1,
          group_type: "EXT"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          group_type: "INT"
        }
      ],
      address_type: {
        city_name: "nashik",
        state: {
          code_name: "MH",
          name: "Maharashtra"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function toCamel(o) {
  var newO, origKey, newKey, value
  if (o instanceof Array) {
    return o.map(function(value) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
          value = toCamel(value)
        }
        return value
    })
  } else {
    newO = {}
    for (origKey in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(origKey)) {
        newKey = _.camelCase(origKey)
        value = o[origKey]
        if (value instanceof Array || (value !== null && value.constructor === Object)) {
          value = toCamel(value)
        }
        newO[newKey] = value
      }
    }
  }
  return newO
}

console.log(toCamel(obj));
```

I have used lodash in this code.

Answer (score 1):

I used the code from Donny Verduijn, but found that Date objects were getting converted to `{}`.

I also needed the ability to convert from snakeToCamel and camelToSnake so I added a formatter parameter.

```
export const snakeToCamel = (str: string): string =>
  str.replace(/([_-][a-z])/gi, ($1: string) => $1.toUpperCase().replace('-', '').replace('_', ''));

export const camelToSnake = (str: string): string =>
  str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ($1: string) => `_${$1.toLowerCase()}`);

const isArray = function (
  input: Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[] | unknown
): input is Record<string, unknown>[] {
  return Array.isArray(input);
};

export const isObject = function (
  obj: Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[] | unknown
): obj is Record<string, unknown> {
  return (
    isValidDate(obj) === false &&
    obj === Object(obj) &&
    !Array.isArray(obj) &&
    typeof obj !== 'function'
  );
};

const isValidDate = (value: any) => value instanceof Date;

const modifyObjectKeys = function <T>(input: T, formatter: (word: string) => string): T {
  return (function recurse<K extends Record<string, unknown> | Record<string, unknown>[] | unknown>(
    input: K
  ): K {
    if (isObject(input)) {
      return Object.keys(input).reduce(
        (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, { [formatter(key)]: recurse(input[key]) }),
        {} as K
      );
    } else if (isArray(input)) {
      return input.map((i) => recurse(i)) as K;
    }
    return input;
  })(input);
};

/**
 *
 * @param input Object to convert keys to camelCase
 * @returns Object with keys converted to camelCase
 */
export const camelize = function <T>(input: T): T {
  return modifyObjectKeys(input, snakeToCamel);
};

/**
 *
 * @param input Object to convert keys to snake_case
 * @returns Object with keys converted to snake_case
 */
export const snakeify = function <T>(input: T): T {
  return modifyObjectKeys(input, camelToSnake);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use npm `json-case-handler` which will allow you to do this in one line.

It can convert any nested objects

For your case, you can do this :

```
const jcc = require('json-case-convertor')
const camelCasedJson = jcc.camelCaseKeys(yourjsonData)
```

Answer (score 0):

FP approach solution with lodash/fp

```js
import { camelCase, toPairs, fromPairs, map, compose, isArray, isObject } from 'lodash/fp';

const convertAllKeysToCamelCase = compose(
  fromPairs,
  map(([key, value]) => {
    if (isArray(value)) {
      return [camelCase(key), map(convertAllKeysToCamelCase, value)];
    }

    if (isObject(value)) {
      return [camelCase(key), convertAllKeysToCamelCase(value)];
    }

    return [camelCase(key), value];
  }),
  toPairs
);

convertAllKeysToCamelCase(myObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was recently updated, hence here is another solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Using a well documented library for the iteration might make it a bit easier to adjust your code should that ever be necessary.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@19.0.5/lib/index.min.js';

const obj = { vt_core_random: { user_details: { first_name: 'xyz', last_name: 'abc', groups: [{ id: 1, group_type: 'EXT' }, { id: 2, group_type: 'INT' }], address_type: { city_name: 'nashik', state: { code_name: 'MH', name: 'Maharashtra' } } } } };

const toCamel = (str) => str.replace(
  /([_-][a-z])/gi,
  (char) => char.toUpperCase().replace('-', '').replace('_', '')
);

objectScan(['**'], {
  filterFn: ({ parent, property, value }) => {
    if (typeof property === 'string') {
      const camelized = toCamel(property);
      if (camelized !== property) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        parent[camelized] = value;
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        delete parent[property];
      }
    }
  }
})(obj);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
/* => {
  "vtCoreRandom": {
    "userDetails": {
      "groups": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "groupType": "EXT"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "groupType": "INT"
        }
      ],
      "addressType": {
        "state": {
          "name": "Maharashtra",
          "codeName": "MH"
        },
        "cityName": "nashik"
      },
      "lastName": "abc",
      "firstName": "xyz"
    }
  }
} */
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)